# Exact alignment of Radio buttons in Rows and Columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How do I align Radio buttons exactly in HORIZONTAL ROWS and at the same time exactly in VERTICAL COLUMNS. I have to align radio buttons in four rows. The radio buttons are like so:

[image]

whenever the text is bigger, the radio buttons move to the right. If the text associated with radio button is shorter then radio buttons move to the left. I want them to be aligned properly in rows and columns.Below is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">A</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">B</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3"> cccc</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">ssss</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">rrrr </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">sdsdsd</label>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">jjjjjj</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">jjjj</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">rtrtrtrtrtrtrtrtrt </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">hhhhhhhh</label>
    </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">jjjjjj</label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use flex and justify-content property, for further help you need to share html and css code.

Comment: I updated my question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bootstrap for this

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><li>A</li></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><li>B</li></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><li>ccc</li></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><li>GGG</li></div>
</div>
```

Please refer for more details:- https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex_structure&stacked=h

Comment: Happy to help! @Anjali

Answer (score 1):

> using bootstrap `class="form-check-inline"` you can create a radio button inline.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <h1>Radio Buttons</h1>
 <br>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">A</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">B</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">C</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">D</label>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">A</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">B</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">C </label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">D</label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think your query will be solved. Thank You..!

Comment: you created the label of same size, if you different size, it wont work

Answer (score 1):

I can think of wrapping around the classes will give your result.

> Since you need to retain horizontal and vertical alignment you have to fix the width of the blocks and make it wrap to the next line when there is more data.

you can try something like this:

```css
.Align {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;  
}

.form-check-inline {
  width: 22%; /* Fix the block, ofcourse it will work for all screens */
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.form-check-label {
  padding:2px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word; 
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 Align">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">A</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">B</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3"> cccc</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</label>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="col-lg-12 Align">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">ssss</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">rrrr </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">sdsdsd</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 Align">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">jjjjjj</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">jjjj</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">rtrtrtrtrtrtrtrtrt </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">hhhhhhhh</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 Align">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">jjjjjj</label>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```